# Table rates unable to import excel file for Belize country

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, table-rates

I am trying to import the table rates file. I want the different rates based on Belize districts. I found district codes on google : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:BZ
Tried these codes but the error is : `The region or state in row number "3" is incorrect. Please verify region or state`.
Also tried these codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIPS_region_codes_(A%E2%80%93C)#BH:_Belize
But the same issue and Belize is also not supporting the Zip/Postal codes. If anyone know how I can differentiate the 6 districts of the Belize country please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has no region information for BZ. Add the districts to the `directory_country_region` database table for the CSV upload to work.

Comment: let me try this